# How to use Hungarian tax reporting application called ABEVJAVA on Mac?

Tags: macos, java

I have installed Hungarian tax reporting software called ABEVJAVA. I put into my home folder. Then for test it I downloaded a report template called NAV_1408.jnlp On windows I have to double click it, and after that in ABEVJAVA a new item will appear to use the new report.

But on Mac I can not double click it. I tried to run run jnpl file from terminal with JAVA like this below, but I get an error. What can I do now to get it work on Mac?

```
Ks-MacBook-Air:~ kukodajanos$ java /Users/kj/Downloads/NAV_1408.jnlp 
Error: Could not find or load main class .Users.kj.Downloads.NAV_1408.jnlp
Ks-MacBook-Air:~ kukodajanos$
```

Comment: What version of Java?

Comment: java version "1.7.0_60"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't run by double clicking the JNPL file. Other way needs: right click + Open With + JAVA WEB START

[image]

I found it in the manual on NAV's website: http://nav.gov.hu/data/cms126069/sugo.pdf

You can look up the 'Mac' keyword.